# Recovered database files can't be attached

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql, recovery

I have recovered my hard drive with my databases mdf and ldf files. When I want to attach them I get a 9004 error:

> Error: 9004, Severity: 21, State: 1.
>   An error occurred while processing the log for database 'mydb'.  If possible, restore from backup. If a backup is not available, it might be necessary to rebuild the log.

I have already tried following this advice:

> Create an empty database with the same name and physical file layout, shut down the server, swap in the files you want to attach in place of the empty DB files, and start the server.  The database should come up in suspect mode.  You can then `ALTER DATABASE <foo> SET EMERGENCY` to put it in emergency mode, and then run `CHECKDB REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS`.  This will pull as much data as possible out of the log to make the database consistent, but may have to delete some data in order to make the database consistent.  This is the option which is most likely to get the maximum data back.

I also tried this solution:

> You can attempt to use the `CREATE DATABASE FOR ATTACH_REBUILD_LOG` to see if that will bring it back.  If the database was cleanly shut down, you MIGHT be able to succeed.  There is also the chance that the database will be inconsistent or corrupt if there are transactions which could not be rolled back.  You should in any event run `DBCC CHECKDB REPAIR_ALLOW_DATA_LOSS` to make your database consistent.  In this event, SQL Server will make no attempt to mine information from the log.  It will ignore the contents of the log.  If there were transactions in process no rollback will be possible, so the `ALLOW_DATA_LOSS` will be required.

Is there another solution I can try?

Comment: What happened after you tried each proposed solution in your question?

Comment: Simply put: Not all file corruptions are recoverable, sorry. This is why we are prudent about backups, and sometimes it takes an expensive lesson like this to fully understand why a backup and recovery strategy is so important.